# Error when-> output: rticles::plos_article used in RMarkdown,

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

When I used,

```
Output: rticles::plos_article in RMarkdown,
```

I get the following error after I knit the .Rcode

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `PLOS-submission-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found: using draft setting.
```

The output using

```
xfun::session_info(c('tinytex', 'rmarkdown'))
```

is

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan), RStudio 0.99.903

Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / 
en_US.UTF-8

Package version:
  backports_1.1.0 base64enc_0.1.3 digest_0.6.13   evaluate_0.10.1
  graphics_3.3.1  grDevices_3.3.1 highr_0.6       htmltools_0.3.6
  jsonlite_1.5    knitr_1.20      magrittr_1.5    markdown_0.8   
  methods_3.3.1   mime_0.5        Rcpp_0.12.14    rmarkdown_1.10 
  rprojroot_1.2   stats_3.3.1     stringi_1.1.5   stringr_1.2.0  
  tinytex_0.6.4   tools_3.3.1     utils_3.3.1     xfun_0.3       
  yaml_2.1.14
```

Output from Tinytex log file is given below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.7.29)  31 JUL 2018 09:55
entering extended mode restricted \write18 enabled. %&-line parsing enabled. 

**Enisi-draft1.tex
(./Enisi-draft1.tex LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.st
y
Package: geometry 2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.st
y
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.st
y
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count88
\Gm@cntv=\count89
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count90
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen103
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen104
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen105
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen107
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen108
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen110
\Gm@dimlist=\toks15
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks16
\ex@=\dimen111
)) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen112
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 213.
\uproot@=\count92
\leftroot@=\count93
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 375.
\classnum@=\count94
\DOTSCASE@=\count95
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 472.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 475.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 596.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box26
\strutbox@=\box27
\big@size=\dimen113
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 712.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 713.
\macc@depth=\count96
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count97
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count98
\dspbrk@lvl=\count99
\tag@help=\toks17
\row@=\count100
\column@=\count101
\maxfields@=\count102
\andhelp@=\toks18
\eqnshift@=\dimen114
\alignsep@=\dimen115
\tagshift@=\dimen116
\tagwidth@=\dimen117
\totwidth@=\dimen118
\lineht@=\dimen119
\@envbody=\toks19
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks20
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2817.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2818.
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
Package: amssymb 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty
Package: amsfonts 2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
\symAMSa=\mathgroup4
\symAMSb=\mathgroup5
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathfrak' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 106.
))
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/changepage/changepage.
sty
Package: changepage 2009/10/20 v1.0c check page and change page layout
\c@cp@cntr=\count103
\cp@tempcnt=\count104
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/04/06 v1.3b Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks21
\inpenc@posthook=\toks22
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/utf8x.def
File: utf8x.def 2004/10/17 UCS: Input encoding UTF-8
)) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucs.sty
Package: ucs 2013/05/11 v2.2 UCS: Unicode input support

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/data/uni-global.de
f
File: uni-global.def 2013/05/13 UCS: Unicode global data
)
\uc@secondtry=\count105
\uc@combtoks=\toks23
\uc@combtoksb=\toks24
\uc@temptokena=\toks25
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp)               5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp)               4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp)               3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp)               2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp)               1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp)               0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp)             Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp)             only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp)             Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp)             See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.

Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/marvosym/marvosym.st
y
Package: marvosym 2011/07/20 v2.2 Martin Vogel's Symbols font definitions
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.s
ty
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
))
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestr
ing.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.s
ty
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.st
y
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.st
y
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
))))
\c@section@level=\count106
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 355.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 355.
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.st
y
Package: hyperref 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hype
rref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)


(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-gene
ric.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `infwarerr' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ltxcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifluatex' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifvtex' (already loaded).
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `ifpdf' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `etexcmds' (already loaded).
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `kvsetkeys' (already loaded).
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `refcount' (already loaded).
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen120
\Hy@linkcounter=\count107
\Hy@pagecounter=\count108
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count109    
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.c
fg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4509.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4514.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4517.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4524.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4529.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4762.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count110
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip11
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5115.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen121
\Fld@menulength=\count111
\Field@Width=\dimen122
\Fld@charsize=\dimen123
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6369.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6374.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6377.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6384.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6389.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6394.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6439.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6443.
\Hy@abspage=\count112
\c@Item=\count113
\c@Hfootnote=\count114
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
\Fld@listcount=\count115
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count116    
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilechec
k.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip46
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty
Package: lineno 2005/11/02 line numbers on paragraphs v4.41
\linenopenalty=\count117
\output=\toks26
\linenoprevgraf=\count118
\linenumbersep=\dimen124
\linenumberwidth=\dimen125
\c@linenumber=\count119
\c@pagewiselinenumber=\count120
\c@LN@truepage=\count121
\c@internallinenumber=\count122
\c@internallinenumbers=\count123
\quotelinenumbersep=\dimen126
\bframerule=\dimen127
\bframesep=\dimen128
\bframebox=\box28
LaTeX Info: Redefining \\ on input line 3056.
)
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.st
y
Package: microtype 2018/01/14 v2.7a Micro-typographical refinements (RS)
\MT@toks=\toks27
\MT@count=\count124
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textls on input line 793.
\MT@outer@kern=\dimen129
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textmicrotypecontext on input line 1339.
\MT@listname@count=\count125

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype-pd
ftex.def
File: microtype-pdftex.def 2018/01/14 v2.7a Definitions specific to pdftex (RS)

LaTeX Info: Redefining \lsstyle on input line 913.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \lslig on input line 913.
\MT@outer@space=\skip47
)
Package microtype Info: Loading configuration file microtype.cfg.

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cf
g
File: microtype.cfg 2018/01/14 v2.7a microtype main configuration file (RS)
)) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.

(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.de
f
File: pdftex.def 2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/colortbl/colortbl.st
y
Package: colortbl 2018/05/02 v1.0c Color table columns (DPC)
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty
Package: array 2018/04/30 v2.4h Tabular extension package (FMi)
\col@sep=\dimen130
\ar@mcellbox=\box29
\extrarowheight=\dimen131
\NC@list=\toks28
\extratabsurround=\skip48
\backup@length=\skip49
\ar@cellbox=\box30
)
\everycr=\toks29
\minrowclearance=\skip50
)
\rownum=\count126
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1352.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
```

The above output is truncated due to character limit

Output from last ~100 lines

```
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ucs/ucsencs.def
File: ucsencs.def 2011/01/21 Fixes to fontencodings LGR, T3
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box31
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 118.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 118.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 118.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 118.
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `Enisi-draft1.out'.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \microtypecontext on input line 118.
Package microtype Info: Generating PDF output.
Package microtype Info: Character protrusion enabled (level 2).
Package microtype Info: Using default protrusion set `alltext'.
Package microtype Info: Automatic font expansion enabled (level 2),
(microtype)             stretch: 20, shrink: 20, step: 1, non-selected.
Package microtype Info: Using default expansion set `basictext'.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of tracking.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of interword spacing.
Package microtype Info: No adjustment of character kerning.
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-cmr.cfg
File: mt-cmr.cfg 2013/05/19 v2.2 microtype config. file: Computer Modern Roman 
(RS)
)
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.
Package lastpage Info: Please have a look at the pageslts package at
(lastpage)             https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts
(lastpage)             ! on input line 118.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msa on input line 128.
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd
File: umsa.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg
File: mt-msa.cfg 2006/02/04 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (a) (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+msb on input line 128.
(/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd
File: umsb.fd 2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
) (/Users/meghnaverma/Library/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg
File: mt-msb.cfg 2005/06/01 v1.0 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (b) (RS)
)
\fe@count@abs@i=\count135
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `cmtt' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `cmss' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <PLOS-submission.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2018-07-26 13:37:16
(epstopdf)                    size: 283246 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <PLOS-submission-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=PLOS-submission-eps-conver
ted-to.pdf PLOS-submission.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 199.
runsystem(repstopdf --outfile=PLOS-submission-eps-converted-to.pdf PLOS-submiss
ion.eps)...executed safely (allowed).

Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <PLOS-submission-eps-converted-to.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `PLOS-submission-eps-converted-to.pdf' not fou
nd: using draft setting.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.199 

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10949 strings out of 494587
 169911 string characters out of 6174677
 312618 words of memory out of 5000000
 14411 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 7821 words of font info for 35 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 42i,11n,43p,312b,300s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Please try to restart R and `devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')`. At least it should give a more informative message.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I get the following message: Error: Failed to compile draft1.tex. See draft1.log for more info.
Execution halted. I am not entirely sure of the content in the log file though.

Comment: Please provide `xfun::session_info('tinytex')` in your post. If you are using macOS, I recommend you to install Homebrew: https://brew.sh

Comment: I already have Homebrew installed.                       
    R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
    Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
    Running under: OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan), 
    RStudio 0.99.903

    Locale: en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 / C / en_US.UTF-8 / en_US.UTF-8 
   Package version:
      tinytex_0.6.4 tools_3.3.1   xfun_0.3

Comment: Please edit your post and provide `xfun::session_info(c('tinytex', 'rmarkdown'))`. Please also consider upgrading R and all your R packages: https://yihui.name/en/2017/05/when-in-doubt-upgrade/

Comment: I edited my post and upgraded R and all the R packages but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in **tinytex** that I just fixed. Could you try `devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')` again? If it still fails to compile the Rmd, please show the output of `Sys.which('gs')` and `Sys.which('brew')`. Thanks!

Comment: I tried installing again but it still fails to compile. The output for 
     Sys.which("brew") is "/usr/local/bin/brew"     and Sys.which('gs') is     gs "". Thank you!

Comment: Could you paste the full log `draft1.log` in your post, too? Does `tinytex::tlmgr_install('epstopdf')` install ghostscript automatically? If you are using MacTeX, you may uninstall it and use TinyTeX instead: `tinytex::install_tinytex()`.

Comment: I am unable to add the full log of `draft1.log` due to character limit here. Yes it installs ghostscript directly. I uninstalled MacTex and used TinyTex  but unfortunately it still fails to compile. Thank you for helping.

Comment: The LaTeX log you provided in the post was based on MacTeX. Could you recompile the document after you install TinyTeX and paste the new log?

Comment: I recompiled the document after I installed TinyTex and posted the output from log file above.

Comment: Thanks! Could you post the last few lines (say, 100 lines) if StackOverflow limits your length of post?

Comment: Yes, I added the last few lines (~100 lines). Thank you for helping.

Comment: Could you restart R and try `devtools::install_github('yihui/tinytex')` again?

Comment: I did and it worked!! Thank you so much for your time and patience. I really appreciate it. I am looking forward to writing this paper in .Rmd!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks a lot for bearing with me through so many steps :)

Answer (score 0):

Through the lengthy debugging process, the reason for the original failure was unclear to me (my guess is that the LaTeX package **epstopdf** was not installed in MacTeX, or there might be something wrong with **ghostscript**). After uninstalling MacTeX and installing [TinyTeX](https://yihui.name/tinytex/), the R package **tinytex** will automatically install the **epstopdf** package as well as **ghostscript**, and the document can be successfully compiled.